# Flex profiler doesn't do anything

Tags: apache-flex, profiling, flexbuilder

My Flex application has some memory problems which I'd like to find using the profiler. However, when I run the profiler from Flex Builder, nothing happens. The appication is run the regular way, but nothing is profiled. The Profiling perspective doesn't event open, and when I open the Profiling perspective, no memory usage is displayed.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What version of Flex/Flex Builder are you using?

Comment: Flex Builder version 3.0.1.205647
Flex Compiler version 10.0.12

Comment: Are you running The debug version Of your as well as the debugging version of Flash Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and I found a solution on this blog -> http://wceii.blogspot.com/2009/12/flex-profiler-socket-timeout-error.html

Adding the line below to the mm.cfg file.

PreloadSwf?={my eclipse workspace}.metadata.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent?.swf?host=localhost&port=9999

- Windows; C:\Documents and Settings\username\mm.cfg
- OSX; /Library/Application Support/Macromedia/mm.cfg
- Linux; home/username/mm.cfg

cyrill

Comment: Oh, actually when I decided to read more thouroughly, the solution did work! However, I still can't profile cause now it throws a different Exception. Another problem to which I do not know the solution. Possibly you could help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356228/referenceerror-error-1065-variable-contextmenuclipboarditems-is-not-defined