# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ContextMenuClipboardItems is not defined

Tags: apache-flex, profiling

I'm trying to use the flex profiler to discover where the performance problems in my app are. However, when I run the app, I get this error message. I don't get this when I run regularly or in debug mode.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ContextMenuClipboardItems is not defined.
    at flash.ui::ContextMenu/initLinkAndClipboardProperties()
    at flash.ui::ContextMenu()
    at mx.core::Application/initContextMenu()[C:\autobuild\3.3.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\Application.as:1154]
    at mx.core::Application/initialize()[C:\autobuild\3.3.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\Application.as:844]
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error often refers to missing assets in the swf file that is expected to be there.

It refers to a missing asset in an MXML file. Make sure that ContextMenuClipboardItems refers to an asset that is included into your SWF file.

If your asset is included make sure it has proper scope for how you are using it. If it needs to be Public then make it public.

It would help if you posted your code but this should get you pointed in the right direction.